# Impossible to change tooltip title in react-chart-js-2

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

I am trying to custom the tooltip popup in char-js and it's not working. I followed the doc and several posts on stackOverflow, but nothing seems to work. If anybody had a solution, I'd be very grateful. Here's the component code:

```
/* eslint-disable max-statements */
import {HorizontalBar} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import ChartWrapper from '../../Dashboards/ChartWrapper/ChartWrapper';

const HorizontalLogChart = ({spamDetails}) => {
  const result = Object.entries(spamDetails).map(([key, value]) => ({label: key, values: parseFloat(value, 10)})).filter((item) => item.values > 0.1 || item.values < -0.1);
  const value = result.map((item) => item.values);
  const label = result.map((item) => item.label);
  const bgColor = value.map((item) => (item > 0 ? 'rgba(255, 107, 107)' : 'rgba(151, 208, 173)'));

  const unmatchedResult = Object.entries(spamDetails).map(([key, number]) => ({label: key, values: parseFloat(number, 10)})).filter((item) => item.values < 0.1 && item.values > -0.1);
  const unmatchedValueArray = unmatchedResult.map((item) => item.values).reduce((acc, currentValue) => acc + currentValue).toFixed(3);

  if (parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10) > 0.5) {
    value.push(parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10));
  } else if (parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10) < -0.5) {
    value.push(parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10));
  } else if (parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10) > 0 && parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10) < 0.5) {
    value.push(0.5);
  } else if (parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10) < 0 && parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10) > -0.5) {
    value.push(-0.5);
  }

  label.push('OTHERS');

  const data = {
    labels: label,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: value,
        label: 'Notes',
        backgroundColor: bgColor,
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
    ],
  };

  const options = {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          beforeTitle: 'arg',
          label: 'pk',
        },
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
  };


  return (

    <ChartWrapper data={data}>
      <HorizontalBar options={options} />
    </ChartWrapper>

  );
};

export default HorizontalLogChart;
```

I tried several syntax and nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import { HorizontalBar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import ChartWrapper from "../../Dashboards/ChartWrapper/ChartWrapper";

const HorizontalLogChart = ({ spamDetails }) => {
  const result = Object.entries(spamDetails)
    .map(([key, value]) => ({ label: key, values: parseFloat(value, 10) }))
    .filter((item) => item.values > 0.1 || item.values < -0.1);
  const value = result.map((item) => item.values);
  const label = result.map((item) => item.label);
  const bgColor = value.map((item) =>
    item > 0 ? "rgba(255, 107, 107)" : "rgba(151, 208, 173)"
  );

  const unmatchedResult = Object.entries(spamDetails)
    .map(([key, number]) => ({ label: key, values: parseFloat(number, 10) }))
    .filter((item) => item.values < 0.1 && item.values > -0.1);
  const unmatchedValueArray = unmatchedResult
    .map((item) => item.values)
    .reduce((acc, currentValue) => acc + currentValue)
    .toFixed(3);

  if (parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10) > 0.5) {
    value.push(parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10));
  } else if (parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10) < -0.5) {
    value.push(parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10));
  } else if (
    parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10) > 0 &&
    parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10) < 0.5
  ) {
    value.push(0.5);
  } else if (
    parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10) < 0 &&
    parseFloat(unmatchedValueArray, 10) > -0.5
  ) {
    value.push(-0.5);
  }

  label.push("OTHERS");

  const data = {
    labels: label,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: value,
        label: "Notes",
        backgroundColor: bgColor,
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
    ],
  };

  const options = {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          beforeTitle: (tooltipItem) => {
            // custom function for beforeTitle
            return `Value for ${tooltipItem[0].label}:`;
          },
          label: (tooltipItem) => {
            // custom function for label
            return `${tooltipItem.formattedValue}%`;
          },
        },
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <ChartWrapper data={data}>
      <HorizontalBar options={options} />
    </ChartWrapper>
  );
};

export default HorizontalLogChart;
```